# Deploying play 2 app to cloudbees issue

Tags: playframework-2.0, cloudbees

Has anyone tried to deploy to cloudbees a play 2 application using this [latest](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Playframework#HDeployingaPlay2application) instructions?

I've done all the steps but when I tried to run this:

```
play cloudbees-deploy
```

I receive:

```
[error] Not a valid command: cloudbees-deploy
[error] Not a valid project ID: cloudbees-deploy
[error] Not a valid configuration: cloudbees-deploy
[error] Not a valid key: cloudbees-deploy (similar: cloudbees-application-id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - there needs to be ~/.bees/bees.config (I adjusted the docs to make that clearer).

Also the import must be there, as mentioned. It is probably preferable to not hard code the keys.

I verified this with play 2.0.4 just today (2.0.1 isn't yet working until a version is pushed that supports the older version of SBT)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved that by putting `import cloudbees.Plugin._` in Build.scala but further errors complaining about missing `username` and so on appeared.

Seems that I had to put this In Build.scala:

```
    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA) 
    .settings(cloudBeesSettings :_*)
    .settings(
  CloudBees.applicationId := Some("my_app")
).settings(
  CloudBees.username := Some("my_username")
).settings(
  CloudBees.apiKey := Some("my_app_key")
).settings(
  CloudBees.apiSecret := Some("my_secret")
).settings(
  CloudBees.host := "https://api.cloudbees.com/api"
)
```

not only `CloudBees.applicationId := Some("my_app")` as they say...

Comment: You had a ~/.bees/bees.config file ?

Comment: Oh and what version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: @Ivan Yes, in my app I put a folder .bees containing a file with bees.config properties but it was strange that those were not taken... Plugin version `addSbtPlugin("com.cloudbees.deploy.play" % "sbt-cloudbees-play-plugin" % "0.3-SNAPSHOT")`

Comment: Please contact me directly at imeredith -at - cloudbees.com, I'll try and go through this in more detail with you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I put `.bees` directory in a wrong path. `%HOME%` directory on a Windows machine can be found typying: `echo %USERPROFILE%` in cmd so this is the correct path where `.bees` folder should be put.